# Ajuda para resolver erro android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou tendo problema com um erro no android studio. Pelo que eu entedi, quando eu executo o projeto, uma "determinada partição, é redimensionada", para um tamanho maior ou ocupa um espaço maior. Ja tentei pesquisar como resolver, porém não deu em nada. Apesar do erro, ele permite que eu "execute a emulação" do aplicativo normalmente.

O erro é o seguinte:

*Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: WARNING: userdata partition is resized from 550 M to 800 M
ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 1
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554*

imagem do erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você vai criar um emulador para o android studio,você tem a opção de escolher a quantidade de armazenamento do emulador, no caso para salvar as informações durante a emulação, pelo oque entendi nesse erro, o software teve algum problema em redimensionar o tamanho da partição de 550 para 800M, a possível solução é excluir esse teu emulador já criado no gerenciador de emuladores, também conhecido como AVD MANAGER, exclui esse emulador lá e cria outro com no max 550M de espaço.

Comment: Cara, deu certo ! Obrigado. No caso, eu nunca vou poder criar um com memoria superior a essa ? Sabe me dizer o porque ?

Comment: Teu computador tens quantos GB de memória ram?